# Defining whitespace before or after a figure or table in ConTeXt mkiv

Tags: floats, context

I am having trouble defining the whitespace before and after an xtable (or a figure for that matter) in ConTeXt mkiv. No matter how I set `spacebefore=`, the result is the same. Here's a MWE showing my problem:

```
\setupfloat[table][spacebefore={\blank[4*big]}]

\setupxtable[frame=off]
\setupxtable[head][topframe=on,bottomframe=on]
\setupxtable[body][]
\setupxtable[foot][bottomframe=on]


\starttext

\input douglas
\startplacetable[title={Cost Overview}]
\startxtable
\startxtablehead[head]
\startxrow
\startxcell[align=right]  \stopxcell
\startxcell[align=right] (\$) \stopxcell
\stopxrow
\stopxtablehead
\startxtablebody[body]
\startxrow
\startxcell[align=right] Lodging \stopxcell
\startxcell[align=right] 150 \stopxcell
\stopxrow
\startxrow
\startxcell[align=right] Fee \stopxcell
\startxcell[align=right] 160 \stopxcell
\stopxrow
\startxrow
\startxcell[align=right] Meals \stopxcell
\startxcell[align=right] 100 \stopxcell
\stopxrow
\startxrow
\startxcell[align=right] Van \stopxcell
\startxcell[align=right] 175 \stopxcell
\stopxrow
\stopxtablebody
\startxtablefoot[foot]
\startxrow
\startxcell[align=right] Other Outings \stopxcell
\startxcell[align=right] 40 \stopxcell
\stopxrow
\stopxtablefoot
\stopxtable
\stopplacetable

\input douglas

\stoptext
```

Comment: @JohnGrasty You can only set whitespace for all floats (e.g. `\setupfloat[spacebefore=4*big]`) but not for a single instance (e.g. `\setupfloat[table][spacebefore=4*big]`).

Comment: @Metafox: I would consider this a bug. Let's discuss this on the mailing list.

Comment: @Metafox Thanks so much. The obsessive side of me would love the flexibility of setting it for each instance, but in reality, I suspect the setting for all floats is what I need. If make this an answer, I'll be happy to accept it. --Edit. I just saw Aditya response. I'll accept whatever the official answer ends up being.  Thank you both for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some environment with instances let you set certain options only for all instances and not only a single one, the `spacebefore` and `spaceafter` settings for floats are such a option.

This means only the following setup is possible

```
\setupfloat
  [spacebefore=2*line,
    spaceafter=2*line]
```

but not this one where I change only the values for the `table` instance.

```
\setupfloat
  [table]
  [spacebefore=2*line,
    spaceafter=2*line]
```